# Vectorizing/parallelizing dictionary sympy sum

Tags: python, sympy, permutation

I have a calculation (written in python) where the output is a dictionary with keys being tuples of ints (permutations) and values being `sympy` objects (multivariate polynomials). The computation is done on a (possibly large) number of intermediate dictionaries that all have the same keys, with each dictionary corresponding to a list of permutations, and these intermediate dictionaries could all be processed in parallel (but are currently not). After this calculation that could be done in parallel, the intermediate dictionaries are all summed up to get the result. I'm trying to speed up the calculation as best I can.

```
def schubmult(perm_dict,v):
    vn1 = inverse(v)
    th = theta(vn1)
    if th[0]==0:
        return perm_dict
    mu = permtrim(uncode(th))
    vmu = permtrim(mulperm(list(v),mu))
    inv_vmu = inv(vmu)
    inv_mu = inv(mu)
    ret_dict = {}
    # vpaths is the indexing set of the intermediate dictionaries
    vpaths = [([vmu],1)]
    
    # construct vpaths
    for i in range(len(th)):
        k = i+1
        vpaths2 = []
        for path,s in vpaths:
            last_perm = path[-1]
            newperms = kdown_perms(last_perm,th[i],k)
            for new_perm,s2 in newperms:
                new_perm2 = permtrim(new_perm)
                if i == len(th)-1 and tuple(new_perm2) != (1,2):
                    continue
                path2 = [*path,new_perm2]
                vpaths2 += [(path2,s*s2)]
        vpaths = vpaths2
        
    for u,val in perm_dict.items():
        inv_u = inv(u)
        vpathsums = [{u: val} for p in vpaths]        
        for index in range(len(th)):
            # begin with empty dictionaries for each path
            new_sum_dicts = [{} for p in vpaths]
            for up in vpathsums[0].keys():                
                inv_up = inv(up)
                # for each permutation, generate a new set of permutations that contribute to the sum
                newperms = elem_sym_perms(up,min(th[index],(inv_mu-(inv_up-inv_u))-inv_vmu),th[index])                
                # loop over each new permutation
                for up2 in newperms:
                    # this is the part that could be done completely in parallel
                    for i in range(len(vpaths)):
                        new_sum_dicts[i][up2] = new_sum_dicts[i].get(up2,0)+vpathsums[i].get(up,0)*elem_sym_func(th[index],index+1,up,up2,vpaths[i][0][index],vpaths[i][0][index+1],var2,var3)
            vpathsums = new_sum_dicts
        # sum up the results at the end
        for ep in vpathsums[0].keys():
            acc = ret_dict.get(ep,0)
            for i in range(len(vpathsums)):             
                acc += vpaths[i][1]*vpathsums[i][ep]
            ret_dict[ep] = acc
```

As in the comments in the code, the innermost loop is what could be done in parallel. I'm looking to a way to parallelize the inner loop and efficiently compute the sum. I'm open to new ways to represent the result (other than permutation dictionaries). `vpaths` is very large in general. Runtimes are highly dependent on the number of inversions of `u` and `v`. For `v` with 15 inversions and `u` with 0 inversions (increasing sequence), the runtime is 2 minutes. For `v` with 15 inversions and `u` with 10 inversions, runtime is 156 minutes. The whole program is 241 lines. If more detail is needed I will edit the question to add more code.

It was suggested I post a program that can be executed for testing. I am posting the program, minus arg parsing and with a single function call, below. Change the tuple and the list in the function call (to permutations of 1,...,n only, for some n, which can be different for the two permutations, where the last element of the permutation cannot be the largest element in the list/tuple, unless it is (1,2), which is fully reduced). Since I wrote this I switched from sympy to symengine, which increases the speed by an order of magnitude. The question remains though (it could always be faster).

```
from symengine import *
import sys
from functools import cache, reduce

n = 100
var = tuple([symbols(f"x{'['}{i}{']'}") for i in range(0,n)])
var2 = tuple([symbols(f"y{'['}{i}{']'}") for i in range(0,n)])
var3 = tuple([symbols(f"z{'['}{i}{']'}") for i in range(0,n)])

def inv(perm):
    res = 0    
    for i in range(len(perm)-1):
        for j in range(i+1,len(perm)):
            if perm[i]>perm[j]:
                res+=1
    return res

def mulperm(perm1,perm2):
    if len(perm1)<len(perm2):
        return [perm1[perm2[i]-1] if perm2[i]<=len(perm1) else perm2[i] for i in range(len(perm2))]
    else:
        return [perm1[perm2[i]-1] for i in range(len(perm2))]+perm1[len(perm2):]

def uncode(cd):
    if cd == []:
        return [1,2]
    max_required = max([cd[i]+i for i in range(len(cd))])
    cd += [0 for i in range(len(cd),max_required)]
    fullperm = [i+1 for i in range(len(cd)+1)]
    perm = []
    for i in range(len(cd)):
        perm += [fullperm[cd[i]]]
        fullperm.pop(cd[i])
    perm += [fullperm[0]]
    return perm

def code(perm):
    ret = []
    for i in range(len(perm)-1):
        ret += [0]
        for j in range(i+1,len(perm)):
            if perm[i]>perm[j]:
                ret[-1] += 1
    return ret

def inverse(perm):
    retperm = [0 for i in range(len(perm))]
    for i in range(len(perm)):
        retperm[perm[i]-1] = i+1
    return retperm

def permtrim(perm):
    while len(perm) > 2 and perm[-1] == len(perm):
        perm.pop()
    return perm
    
def has_bruhat_descent(perm,i,j):
    if perm[i]<perm[j]:
        return False
    for p in range(i+1,j):
        if perm[i]>perm[p] and perm[p]>perm[j]:
            return False
    return True
    
def has_bruhat_ascent(perm,i,j):
    if perm[i]>perm[j]:
        return False
    for p in range(i+1,j):
        if perm[i]<perm[p] and perm[p]<perm[j]:
            return False
    return True    

def elem_sym_perms(orig_perm,p,k):    
    total_list = [orig_perm]
    up_perm_list = [(orig_perm,k)]
    ## inv_mu -inv_vmu >=  pp
    for pp in range(p):
        perm_list = []
        for up_perm, jj in up_perm_list:    
            up_perm2 = list(up_perm) + [len(up_perm)+1]
            if len(up_perm2) < k + 1:
                up_perm2 += [i+1 for i in range(len(up_perm2),k+2)]
            pos_list = [i for i in range(k) if (((i>=len(orig_perm) and up_perm2[i] == i+1) or (i<len(orig_perm) and orig_perm[i] == up_perm[i])))]
            for j in range(jj,len(up_perm2)):
                for i in pos_list:            
                    if has_bruhat_ascent(up_perm2,i,j):
                        up_perm2[i],up_perm2[j] = up_perm2[j],up_perm2[i]
                        new_perm = permtrim(list(up_perm2))
                        up_perm2[i],up_perm2[j] = up_perm2[j],up_perm2[i]
                        new_perm_add = tuple(new_perm)
                        perm_list += [(new_perm_add,j)]
                        total_list+=[new_perm_add]
        up_perm_list = perm_list
    return total_list

def kdown_perms(perm,p,k):
    full_perm_list = [(list(perm),1)]
    down_perm_list = [(list(perm),1)]
    if len(perm)<k:
        return full_perm_list
    for pp in range(p):
        down_perm_list2 = []
        for perm2, s in down_perm_list:
            if len(perm2)<k:
                continue
            a2 = k-1
            in_list = [i for i in range(0,len(perm2)) if (i!=a2 and perm2[i]==perm[i])]
            for b in in_list:
                s2 = s
                if b < a2:
                    i,j,s2 = b,a2,-s                    
                else:
                    i,j = a2,b
                if has_bruhat_descent(perm2,i,j):
                    new_perm = [*perm2]
                    new_perm[a2],new_perm[b] = new_perm[b],new_perm[a2]
                    new_perm_trim = permtrim(new_perm)
                    down_perm_list2 += [(new_perm_trim,s2)]
                    full_perm_list += [(new_perm_trim,s2)]        
        down_perm_list = down_perm_list2
    return full_perm_list
    
def theta(perm):
    cd = code(perm)
    for i in range(len(cd)-1,0,-1):
        for j in range(i-1,-1,-1):
            if cd[j] < cd[i]:
                cd[i]+=1
    cd.sort(reverse=True)
    return cd

@cache
def elem_sym_poly_unshifted(p,k):
    if p>k:
        return 0
    if p == 0:
        return 1
    return elem_sym_poly_unshifted(p,k-1)+(var[k]-var2[k+1-p])*elem_sym_poly_unshifted(p-1,k-1)    

def elem_sym_poly(p,k,varl1,varl2):
    return elem_sym_poly_unshifted(p,k).subs({key:value for key,value in ([(var2[i],varl2[i]) for i in range(len(varl2))]+[(var[i],varl1[i]) for i in range(len(varl1))])})

def elem_sym_func(k,i,u1,u2,v2,v1,varl1,varl2):
    udiff = inv(u2)-inv(u1)
    vdiff = inv(v2)-inv(v1)
    newk = k - udiff
    p = k-udiff-vdiff
    if newk<0 or p<0:
        return 0
    if p == 0:
        return 1
    u3 = list(u2) + [j+1 for j in range(len(u2),k)]
    yvar_index = [u3[j] for j in range(k) if (j>=len(u2) or (j>=len(u1) and u2[j] == j+1) or (j<len(u1) and u1[j] == u2[j]))]
    v3 = list(v2) + [j+1 for j in range(len(v2),i)]
    zvar_index = [v3[j] for j in range(len(v3)) if (j == i-1 or (j>=len(v1) and v3[j]!=j+1) or (j<len(v1) and v1[j]!=v3[j]))]
    return elem_sym_poly(p,newk,[1]+[(varl1[yvar_index[a]]) for a in range(len(yvar_index))],[1]+[(varl2[zvar_index[b]]) for b in range(len(zvar_index))])

def schubmult(perm_dict,v):
    vn1 = inverse(v)
    th = theta(vn1)
    if th[0]==0:
        return perm_dict
    mu = permtrim(uncode(th))
    vmu = permtrim(mulperm(list(v),mu))
    inv_vmu = inv(vmu)
    inv_mu = inv(mu)
    ret_dict = {}
    vpaths = [([vmu],1)]
    
    for i in range(len(th)):
        k = i+1
        vpaths2 = []
        for path,s in vpaths:
            last_perm = path[-1]
            newperms = kdown_perms(last_perm,th[i],k)
            for new_perm,s2 in newperms:
                new_perm2 = permtrim(new_perm)
                if i == len(th)-1 and tuple(new_perm2) != (1,2):
                    continue
                path2 = [*path,new_perm2]
                vpaths2 += [(path2,s*s2)]
        vpaths = vpaths2
        
    for u,val in perm_dict.items():
        inv_u = inv(u)
        vpathsums = [{u: val} for p in vpaths]        
        for index in range(len(th)):
            new_sum_dicts = [{} for p in vpaths]
            for up in vpathsums[0].keys():                
                inv_up = inv(up)
                newperms = elem_sym_perms(up,min(th[index],(inv_mu-(inv_up-inv_u))-inv_vmu),th[index])                
                for up2 in newperms:                    
                    for i in range(len(vpaths)):
                        new_sum_dicts[i][up2] = new_sum_dicts[i].get(up2,0)+vpathsums[i][up]*elem_sym_func(th[index],index+1,up,up2,vpaths[i][0][index],vpaths[i][0][index+1],var2,var3)
            vpathsums = new_sum_dicts
        for ep in vpathsums[0].keys():
            acc = ret_dict.get(ep,0)
            for i in range(len(vpathsums)):                
                acc += vpaths[i][1]*vpathsums[i][ep]
            ret_dict[ep] = acc
    return ret_dict


# do bigger permutations for longer computation times
schubmult({(2, 1, 7, 6, 5, 3, 4): 1},[1, 5, 7, 9, 10, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8])
```

For full disclosure, so this isn't just a random piece of code, this is code for multiplying [double Schubert polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schubert_polynomial#Double_Schubert_polynomials) in two different sets of coefficient variables and re-expressing the product in terms of the basis of double Schubert polynomials over one of the sets of variables. Some of the polynomials are constant, and computing the constant values alone is a #P-complete problem, so "efficient" is relative here, as anything will likely be exponential time (in the number of inversions).

Comment: `vectorizing` is (usually) something we do with `numpy` arrays. The term isn't usually usedd in `sympy` context.  Also `dicts` can't be 'vectorized'.  Keys are used individually.

Comment: @hpaulj Removed the term "vectorize." But I assume you get the idea of what I'm trying to do. There's inefficiency here that typically could be sped up easily if my vector representation (in the mathematical sense of "vector") weren't as permutation dictionaries.

Comment: the question might benefit from augmenting the sample code such that it becomes an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) . this would allow others to run it and study it further.

Comment: @wsdookadr I could remove the arg parsing, etc. and reduce the program to one high level function call on a test case, but the minimal amount of code needed is still about 200 lines. Is that too much?

Comment: @wsdookadr I posted it below.

Comment: `joblib` makes batch-type things easy to parallelize.

Comment: @Him So I just "successfully" tried it but it looks like the multiprocessing adds way too much overhead to be worthwhile. It would be good for multithreading in another language, but each portion takes too short a time for it to be worth spinning up another process.

Comment: @MattSamuel "too much overhead" you should do stuff parallel in batches, not individually.  Have each thread do 1000 things, get all those results and put them together.

Comment: @Him I did some profiling and the slowdown areas were actually a bit surprising. The worst offenders are computing the number of inversions (inv) and computing elem_sym_func, which is called tens of thousands of times. I managed to vectorize it by reversing the order of summation and using numpy arrays. That modification doesn't save any time really, I'm guessing with symengine objects numpy isn't really "vectorizing" it.

Comment: Removing the cached elem_sym_poly_unshifted and unrolling elem_sym_poly saves a lot of time, and sparingly computing the number of inversions (and caching the inversion function) saves a lot of time as well. I have an example where the old verrsion takes 5 minutes, 39 seconds and the new version takes 3 minutes, 42 seconds. Besides summing the arrays, there isn't really anything that can be parallelized. Not sure if I should answer the question. The site gives me a warning when I try that.

Comment: @Him I have an "old old version" that is faster for small examples, giving 9 seconds when the original posted here does 30 seconds and the optimized version takes 13, but it uses a less structured method and the paths can wander farther, and for larger cases it chokes. I have one example where the posted version takes 42 seconds, the optimized version takes 20 seconds, and I started the old old version minutes ago, still running, and I just checked and it's using 7GB of virtual memory so I have to kill it.

Comment: That's a lot of code.  If you want more help here - find the bottleneck, refactor that into a function or two, (code-golf: in how few lines can you reproduce the bottleneck?), provide a concrete input to that function here as a example case, along with the output.

Comment: @Him Working on that, it's a little tough because it's a pretty complex problem, but I did also find an optimization eliminating a situation when it was literally doing nothing useful...it was basically copying the dict item by item because a value was 0. It saved 50 seconds out of 200 in a profiled run.

Comment: @Him I've been trying joblib on the final summation and invariably it has been slower. I managed to gain some speed with the right options though: the memory tends to blow up because it's passing huge arrays around, but they're all separate. If I require sharedmem there's no blocking and the passing doesn't happen, it saves some time if vpaths is large. I saved 26 seconds on 263 when vpaths had 642 elements. Significant, but it's pointing towards using a different language so it can just use threads rather than spinning up processes.

Comment: @Him Actually I just watched it on that run and it's not actually using more CPUs with sharedmem. But it's faster anyway. That's weird.

Answer (score 1):

I incrementally worked to answer my own question. I reversed the orders of the inner loops and used numpy, and for large cases used joblib. It's not shown here, but I also modified `elem_sym_perms`, `elem_sym_func`, and `kdown_perms` to avoid computing the number of inversions of the permutation, as that was taking a lot of time (the time complexity isn't really the issue as the sizes of the permutations are small, it's just the sheer number of calls that's the problem). The overall savings in both time and memory is huge. The time when multiprocessing in joblib would be useful, it uses too much extra memory, and the operating system kills the process (for sufficiently large cases). However, I had it use threading when the size of the array is at least 300, and for some reason a significant amount of time is saved that way, even though it's still only using one CPU. The joblib doc does mention numpy operations are good candidates for threading.

```
def pairsum(ep,arr):
    return (ep,np.sum(arr))

def schubmult(perm_dict,v):
    vn1 = inverse(v)
    th = theta(vn1)
    if th[0]==0:
        return perm_dict        
    mu = permtrim(uncode(th))
    vmu = permtrim(mulperm(list(v),mu))
    inv_vmu = inv(vmu)
    inv_mu = inv(mu)
    ret_dict = {}
    vpaths = [([(vmu,0)],1)]
    while th[-1] == 0:
        th.pop()
    for i in range(len(th)):
        k = i+1
        vpaths2 = []
        for path,s in vpaths:
            last_perm = path[-1][0]
            newperms = kdown_perms(last_perm,th[i],k)
            for new_perm,s2,vdiff in newperms:
                new_perm2 = permtrim(new_perm)
                if i == len(th)-1 and (len(new_perm2) != 2 or new_perm2[0]!=1):
                    continue
                path2 = [*path,(new_perm2,vdiff)]
                vpaths2 += [(path2,s*s2)]
        vpaths = vpaths2
    arr0 = [0 for vpath in vpaths]
    for u,val in perm_dict.items():
        inv_u = inv(u)
        vpathsums = {u: val*np.array([vpath[1] for vpath in vpaths])}
        for index in range(len(th)):            
            newpathsums = {}
            for up, arr in vpathsums.items():
                inv_up = inv(up)
                newperms = elem_sym_perms(up,min(th[index],(inv_mu-(inv_up-inv_u))-inv_vmu),th[index])                            
                for up2, udiff in newperms:                    
                    newpathsums[up2] = newpathsums.get(up2,np.array(arr0))+arr*[elem_sym_func(th[index],index+1,up,up2,vpaths[i][0][index][0],vpaths[i][0][index+1][0],udiff,vpaths[i][0][index+1][1],var2,var3) for i in range(len(vpaths))]
            vpathsums = newpathsums
        if len(vpaths)<300:
            ret_dict = add_perm_dict({ep: np.sum(arr) for ep,arr in vpathsums.items()},ret_dict)
        else:
            ret_dict = add_perm_dict(dict(Parallel(n_jobs=-1,require='sharedmem')(delayed(pairsum)(ep,arr) for ep,arr in vpathsums.items())),ret_dict)            
    return ret_dict
```

This is definitely vectorized and I parallelized a small part of it.

I can't really post the output because it's massive (I haven't tried, but it would probably take almost an hour to print the output), but timing the two versions, say we run

```
schubmult({(2,1,6,8,5,3,4,7): 1},[1,4,2,3,9,8,5,6,7])
```

The length of `vpaths` is 642, so the `joblib` code kicks in in the new version. On my machine, the new code with `joblib` and `numpy` runs in 4 minutes 1 second on an example run, user time. Multiple runs vary by +/- 6 seconds. Running with the old code, the memory it uses just barely fits into RAM with the programs I have running (so it's not hitting the disk), and it runs in 19 minutes and 18 seconds user time. The joblib savings is significant but modest; it's 4 minutes and 23 seconds user time without `joblib`. Only the end is parallelized, and that takes 74 seconds without joblib, 52 seconds with it. Obviously there is time variation otherwise.

Comment: I don't think anyone is coming across this old question, but anyway I removed the parallelization and found alternative optimizations and this example runs in roughly 1 second!

Answer (score 0):

For parallelizing: You mentioned that the innermost loop of the function is a good candidate for parallelization, and you are correct. By using a library like multiprocessing, you can split the loop into multiple threads or processes and run them in parallel. This can help to reduce the overall runtime of the function, especially if you have a machine with multiple cores.

For vectorizing: You could try using sympy's built-in vectorization capabilities to perform the summation more efficiently. For example, instead of using a loop to iterate over the elements of vpathsums and adding the values to ret_dict, you could try using sympy's Add.as_coeff_add function to add the elements of vpathsums directly.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The problem is that the elements of the sum are an unorthodox type of vector, which are dictionaries with permutations as keys and polynomials as values. Unless sympy has adding across keys of dicts, that doesn't seem like something I could directly plug into a sympy function.